# Search for button in iframe

Tags: java, loops, iframe, pega

I have an application with multiple iframes in the same screen. These iframes have different names every session, so I would like to search within the application for a button within one of the iframes with the name "Pesonal". This iframe-name should be saved to be used in another method. Anybody an idea how to do this?

Comment: do you use some kind of web framework ? Or what are you using to display the iframes ?

Comment: It a screen in Pega. I have not build the application, just trying to automate some tests

Comment: Can you show us a bit code and what u already tried ?

Comment: @Menno: could you please provide more information on this? Are you using HTML rule for this?

Comment: Please close / delete this topic as I have found the solution:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please close / delete this topic as I have found the solution:

```
public WebElement findElement(By locator) {
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    //list all iframes
    List<WebElement> iframeList = driver.findElements(By.tagName(("iframe")));
    final List<WebElement> foundElements = new ArrayList<>();
    iframeList.forEach(iframe -> {

        driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
        List<WebElement> foundElementList = driver.findElements(locator);
        if (foundElementList.size() > 0) {
            foundElements.addAll(foundElementList);
        } else driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    });
    return foundElements.get(0);
}
```

Comment: No need to delete! You can mark your own answer as the one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer